# how to set main-class and class-path in manifest file for java

Tags: java, path

I am trying to get a grasp on Main-Class and Class-Path within a manifest file for java. How come you do not include "C:/" or "/" as part of the path for Main-Class or Class-Path? All of the examples I have seen so far start with a directory name ie. com/test/path or lib/test/path etc...

For example if my java project is in `d:\java\sample_one\` and my .java and .class file are in `sample_one` can my Class-Path be set to `d:\java\sample_one\` ?

Also, why do the paths in Main-Class and Class-Path in some of the various examples I have seen use periods `.` instead of f/b slashes `/\` ?

any help is greatly appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Main-Class attribute in a java manifest file is designed to be used with the `java -jar foo.jar` invocation.  It tells the java command what class within the Jar file should have its `main` method executed when using the above command line syntax.  It basically avoids having to explicitly specify the main class on the command line.

A key thing to remember is that the Main-Class refers to a class WITHIN THE JAR FILE, not on the file system.

Similarly, the Class-Path attribute allows you to specify java jar files that should be on the classpath.  Again, it avoids having to specify them on the command line with the `-classpath` parameter.  Handy if you are packaging an application with supporting jar files and you want to keep the launching syntax simple.

In contrast to the Main-Class attribute, the entries here DO refer to JAR files in the file system.

The dots in the Main-Class identify the package that the class resides in.  It uses the same syntax convention as a package statement in a class, or an import statement.  Think of it as an alternate syntax for the directory structure of your code.

For example, if your code is structured to use a package name com.acme and the main class to run is named Checkout, then the Main-Class attribute would be com.acme.Checkout, and the Checkout.class file would be within the com/acme subdirectory in the JAR file.

Comment: thank you very much. say you include a package, the Main-Class would be set to `some.package.ClassName`? For Class-Path if i only use the current `jar` file do i need a class path?  I was using the following command `jar cvfm file_name.jar manifest.txt *.class` If i set my Class-Path to "d:\java\sample_one\" can i avoid using "*.class" in my command? Do i have to include "d:\" or set it to "java\sample_one\" and run the command from "java/" ?

Comment: If you have all of your classes in the JAR file, and you are not using any third-party JAR files, then I don't believe you need to set the Class-Path at all.

Comment: If you are using packages to organize your code, then yes, the Main-Class would be `some.package.Classname`.  If all of your classes are in the root directory of the JAR, then you just use `ClassName`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about 'avoid using "*.class" in my command'.  Which command?  Creating the JAR?  Running the code?

Comment: when creating the JAR. i am using (and it works) `jar cvfm file_name.jar manifest.txt *.class` If i include a class path for Class-Path, do i need to state *.class in the command i am using?

Comment: To create the JAR file, yes, you need to specify `*.class`. This assumes all of the needed classes are in the current directory. The Class-Path only comes into play when you execute the code via `java -jar file_name.jar`

Comment: Just to be clear, the "dot syntax" is used when referring to "paths" within the code? ie. classes

Comment: Updated the answer.  I'd appreciate you accepting it if it has helped you.

Comment: maybe this is a bit beyond me, but where would it be appropriate to compile and create the JAR file? would you run javac inside of the directory that contains the .java file? or could you run the javac command from anywhere say d:\some\other\dir. Same when creating the JAR file. Do you want to create the JAR file inside of the directory where the .java and .class files are?

Comment: You are now asking a larger question, to wit, what are the techniques used to organize, compile, and package java applications.  There are a variety of approaches and tools like `ant`, `maven`, and `gradle` all address these challenges.  Respectfully suggest you start a new question. And thanks for accepting my answer.